# "Remove All" button for unlimited fields in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, media

I've written a custom module for this functionality where my below code is able to delete the files but I think there should be a better way for doing that!

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $found = FALSE;

  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    $details = $element;
    $found = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
      if (isset($value['#field_name'])) {
        $found = TRUE;
        $details = $value;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($found && variable_get('MYMODULE_' . $details['#field_name'], 0) == 1) {
    $remove_button = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Remove All'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'click',
        'callback' => 'MYMODULE_fields_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
        'method' => 'replace',
       ),
    );
    $element['remove_button'] = $remove_button;
  }
}

function MYMODULE_fields_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_var = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  $nid = $new_var->nid;
  if(is_numeric($nid)){

    // get all fid's attached to this node
    $get_fids = db_select('file_usage', 'fu')
    ->fields('fu')
    ->condition('fu.id', $nid, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllKeyed(0,1);

    foreach ($get_fids as $key => $value) {
      $fids[] = $key;
    }
  }

  // delete all files
  foreach ($fids as $key => $val) {
    $file = file_load($val);
    // file_usage_delete($file, 'MYMODULE');
    file_delete($file, $force = TRUE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could look into this module and get some hints:
https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_fields_remove_button

Comment: @Robin, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this module  but seriously that didn't work for me! I even ask my friends to check out that module, but they also stated that it's not working at their end also. Can you please do me a favor by checking and confirming about this module; i.e. whether it is working on not.